# Where do the log files live in a K8s cluster using the Containerd runtime?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, fluentd, containerd

I'm using the AKS cluster with version 1.19, and I found that this version of K8s using [Containerd](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/#containerd) instead of Dockershim as the container runtime.
I also use Fluentd to collect logs from my spring apps, with k8s version 1.18 it works okay, but with k8s version 1.19 I can't collect logs from my spring app.
I use [this file](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset/blob/master/fluentd-daemonset-azureblob.yaml) for my Fluentd DeamonSet.
I wonder if the log files of my applications are not lived in var/log/containers, is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution here: [use-cri-parser-for-containerdcri-o-logs](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset#use-cri-parser-for-containerdcri-o-logs)

> By default, these images use json parser for /var/log/containers/
> files because docker generates json formatted logs. On the other hand,
> containerd/cri-o use different log format. To parse such logs, you
> need to use cri parser instead.

We need to build a new fluentd image using cri parser, that works for me.